# How to slowly iterate through an array

Tags: java, arrays, shuffle

Hey guys i am making a program that helps me study.(a flash card machine) It basically has a multi dimensional string array that holds the question and its answer. The first challenge i over came was finding a way to randomly pick a question. What i did is, i made another integer array where i shuffled it on start. what i need to do now is used the integer array to display my multi dimensional arrays content. for example. Lets say my int array started like this {1,2,3,4}. After shuffling it, it changed to {3,1,2,4}. Now i want to use that integer array like this. ArrayOfQuestionsAndAnswers[IntegerArray[0]][0] to get the question. What i dont know how to do is get one question at a time. Everytime a button is clicked the Integer array should make to its next int.(that would be 1 in my example.) How can i do this?

My code so far:

Main class:

```
public class Core {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(Variables.getStart()){
            shuffleArray(Variables.getCardNumber());
            Variables.setStart(false);
        }
    }
   public static String getCardQuestion(){
       return Variables.getCards()[0][0];
   }
    public static String getCardAnswer(){
        return Variables.getCards()[0][1];
    }
    // Implementing Fisher–Yates shuffle
    static void shuffleArray(int[] ar)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = ar.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Simple swap
            int a = ar[index];
            ar[index] = ar[i];
            ar[i] = a;
        }
    }

}
```

Variable Class:

```
 public class Variables {
        private static int[] cardNumber ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
        private static String[][] cards = {{"Apostolic Orgin", "Comes form the apostles"},
                {"Biblical inerrancy", "the doctrine that the books are free from error reading the truth"},
                {"Divine Inspiration", "the assistance the holy spirit gave the authors or the bible so they could write"},
                {"fundamentalist approach", "interpretation of the bible and christian doctrine based on the literal meaning og bible's word"}, {"pentateuch", "first 5 books of old testament"},
                {"Torah","Means law, refers to first 5 books of the old testament"},{"Sacred Scripture","The bible/approved list of Judism and Christianity"},
                {"Apostolic Succession","passing on of apostolic preaching and authority from apostles to all bishops"},
                {"encumenical council","gathering of bishops form around the world to address issues of the church"},
                {"Breviary","prayer book that contains the prayers for litergy of the hours"}};
        private static boolean start=true;
        private static int index;

        public static void setIndex(int i){
            index=i;
        }
        public static int getIndex(){
            return index;
        }
        public static void setCardNumber(int[] i){
            cardNumber=i;
        }
        public static int[] getCardNumber(){
            return cardNumber;
        }
        public static void setCards(String[][] i){
            cards=i;
        }
        public static String[][] getCards(){
            return cards;
        }
        public static void setStart(boolean i){
             start=i;
        }
        public static boolean getStart(){
            return start;

        }
    }
```

Basic(un-finished) GUI classs:

```
import study.religion.firstfinal.core.Core;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GUI frame = new GUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GUI() {
        setTitle("Bautista's Religion Review");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        final JLabel label = new JLabel("");
        label.setBounds(32, 22, 356, 160);
        contentPane.add(label);

        JButton btnShowQuestion = new JButton("Show Question");
        btnShowQuestion.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             label.setText("Question: "+Core.getCardQuestion());
            }
        });
        btnShowQuestion.setBounds(62, 216, 121, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnShowQuestion);

        JButton btnShowAnswer = new JButton("Show Answer");
        btnShowAnswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             label.setText("Answer: "+Core.getCardAnswer());
            }
        });
        btnShowAnswer.setBounds(244, 216, 121, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnShowAnswer);
    }

}
```

Comment: what u mean how slowly to iterate through an array?

Comment: You're looking for something driven by `events`. The user clicking a button is an `event` that you need to `listen` for, and then execute code after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not just create a method called `nextQuestion()` in your `Core` class which increments a counter within the class?

Add a integer to your Core class as such:

```
public class Core {

    private int counter = 0;
```

Then add a method in your Core class as such:

```
public void nextQuestion(){
    counter++;
}
```

Modify your `getCardQuestion()` and `getCardAnswer()` to:

```
public static String getCardQuestion(){
    return Variables.getCards()[counter][0];
}

public static String getCardAnswer(){
    return Variables.getCards()[counter][1];
}
```

Perhaps add a button that proceeds to the next question and add a ActionListener which calls `nextQuestion()`.

Please note that the `nextQuestion()` method will keep incrementing without checking for the array boundaries. If you want nextQuestion() to roll over and start again change the statement to such:

```
counter = (counter + 1) % Variables.getCards().length;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your GUI class do the following decleration

```
private int[] RandomInteger = {1,2,3,4}
private int i,j
```

Then as you say, shuffle it.

Now  in nextbutton actionlistener you can do something like that

```
 if(i < RandomInteger.length())
{
  ArrayofQuesiontAndAnswer(randominteger[i++])[j++] //declare i and j as a class member 
}
```

Hope it will help